# Set barButtonItem in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, appdelegate

How can I set `barButtonItem` in `AppDelegate`? Now I have this code:

```
func presentDetailViewController(_ hallID: String) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let navVC = UINavigationController()

    let newDetailVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newDetailVC") as! NewDetailTableViewController

    newDetailVC.hallID = hallID

    navVC.viewControllers = [newDetailVC]

    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(AppDelegate.goToMainVC))
    navVC.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(backItem, animated: true)

    window?.rootViewController = navVC 

    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}

@objc func goToMainVC() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let navVC = UINavigationController()

    let mainVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC") as! PhotoStudiosViewController

    navVC.viewControllers = [mainVC]

    window?.rootViewController = navVC

    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```

`let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Назад", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(AppDelegate.goToMainVC))
            navVC.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(backItem, animated: true)`

This line not helped me and `barButtonItem` still not appear.
How can I create `backButton` with my action `func goToMainVC`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set the navigation item to navigation controller rather you set the navigation item to the navigation bar of viewController

so change your code as

```
let newDetailVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newDetailVC") as! NewDetailTableViewController
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(AppDelegate.goToMainVC))
//navVC.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(backItem, animated: true) this is the issue
newDetailVC.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(backItem, animated: true)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Дмитрий-Деникаев : Am glad I could be of help :)